# Push <link rel="prefetch" ...> into the HTML header

Tags: jquery, ember.js

What is the best way to ask the browser to [prefetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ) a resource in an Ember.js application? The following code in the header of the HTML would do the trick:

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="http://example.com/example.jpg">
```

But I don't know what is the best way to push that code from within the Ember.js application to the HTML header.

I'm not talking about the boot time of an Ember.js application. I'm talking sometime during the usage. There are special scenarios where I know that the app will need a special resource after the next step. I'd like to preload that image/data/whatever at that time.

### Example

```
ember new testapp
ember g route about
```

And adding a `{{#link-to 'about'}}about{{/link-to}}` link to `app/templates/application.hbs`.

Now when ever somebody clicks on that `about` link I want to `prefetch` the file `http://example.com/example.jpg`.

BTW: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-headroom is not a solution for this problem because I want to push the `prefetch` sometime during the run of the application and not at the beginning of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "Ember way" of adding this to `<head>` I'm afraid. The only way do accomplish it yourself at runtime would be to create a new element and append it (using jQuery or regular DOM), possibly in the `setupController` or `model` hooks in your route (I would do it in `setupController` myself).

```
setupController(model, controller) {
  if(!document.getElementById('my-prefetch')) {
    var element = document.createElement('link');
    element.id = 'my-prefetch';
    element.rel = 'prefetch';
    element.href = 'example.jpg';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(element);
  }
}
```